# jQuery select only element with direct child

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am selecting using:

```
$('li:has(>ul)').css('list-style-image', 'url("../images/expand.gif")');// put icon +
```

I want to select only the element `li` that have direct child `ul`. 
The problem is that the css list-style-image applies also to `li` that doesn't have any child.

```
<ul id="tree">
 <li class="opened" style="list-style-image: url(&quot;../images/expand.gif&quot;);">1
     <ul id="tree" class="visibleChild">
        <li class="opened" style="list-style-image: url(&quot;../images/expand.gif&quot;);">9
           <ul id="tree" class="visibleChild">
              <li class="opened">4</li>
              <li class="closed" style="list-style-image: url(&quot;../images/expand.gif&quot;);">5
                 <ul id="tree" class="hiddenChild">
                    <li class="closed">7</li><li class="closed">8</li>
                    <li class="closed">18</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
```

[image]

the number 4 in html doesn't contain any ul but in the image you can see that the css is applied: it has got the expand.gif while it should not have it.

Comment: Post the relevant html.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli added html

Comment: `li { list-style-image: none; }`

Comment: Amazing, it works!Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
li { list-style-image: none; }
```

The style [`list-style-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-image) is inherited, much like `color` is. If you set one `li`'s `list-style-image`, all of it's children will inherit that value. By setting it to `none`, you override the inherited value for all of them to none and your inline style applied by .css overrides it.

Answer (score 0):

As correctly pointed out by [@KevinB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332351/jquery-select-only-element-with-direct-child/46332508#comment79626047_46332508) the issue is CSS inheritance, which neglected to consider.

You can set the `<li>` within the nested `<ul>` `list-style-image` to `"none"` to resolve issue

```js
$(function() {
  $('li:has(>ul)')
  .css('list-style-image', 'url("https://lorempixel.com/50/50/cats")')
  .find("li").css("list-style-image", "none");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>here<ul><li></li></ul></li>
<li>not</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: is it a bug? or is it just doing exactly what it states it does.

Comment: @KevinB Are you purporting that `$("li:has(ul)")` or `$("li:has(>ul)")` should and is intended to match `<li></li>`? Where the description at documentation is _"Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector."_ and the example code given is _"The expression `$( "div:has(p)" )` matches a `<div>` if a `<p>` exists anywhere among its descendants, not just as a direct child."_ how do you draw the conclusion that it is doing what it states it does?

Comment: No, i'm saying you are mis-interpreting your results. https://jsfiddle.net/mj80k7cz/5/

Comment: @KevinB Do you mean because the parent `<li>` has `list-style-image` applied the descendant `<li>` element also has CSS applied?

Comment: the list-style-image property is inherited, setting it on a parent li also sets it on child ones. color is also inherited. see how in my example .css only applies to the correct li and not all the children? Use inspect element and see which elements have a style attribute.

Comment: @KevinB That is a reasonable explaination. Neglected to consider CSS inheritance as issue. `$('li:has(>ul)')
  .css('list-style-image', 'url("https://lorempixel.com/50/50/cats")')
  .find("li").css("list-style-image", "none");` should render expected result

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `:has(selector)` looks for any descendant that matches the selector. So if the `li` contains a nested element that has a `ul` child, it will match this.

Instead, find all the `ul`, then select their parents that are `li`.

```
$('ul').parent('li').css('list-style-image', 'url("../images/expand.gif")');
```

Or you can select all the `ul` that are immediate children of `li`, and then go up to the parent to get back to the `li`.

```
$('li > ul').parent().css('list-style-image', 'url("../images/expand.gif")');
```

Comment: the selector is actually correct, the problem is more css related.

Answer (score 0):

How about this code, you don't need to code classed, they will be added dynamically

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  $('.cat').addClass('plusimageapply'); $('.cat').children().addClass('selectedimage'); $('.cat').children().hide();  $('.cat').each( function(column) {  $(this).click(function(event){  if (this == event.target) {  if($(this).is('.plusimageapply')) {  $(this).children().show();  $(this).removeClass('plusimageapply'); $(this).addClass('minusimageapply');  } else {  $(this).children().hide();  $(this).removeClass('minusimageapply'); $(this).addClass('plusimageapply');  }  }  });  } );  });
```

```css
.plusimageapply{  list-style-image:url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle-addon1/16/text-plus-icon.png); cursor:pointer; }  .minusimageapply{ list-style-image:url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gakuseisean/ivista-2/16/Alarm-Minus-icon.png); cursor:pointer; }  .selectedimage{ list-style-image:url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/16/google-currents-icon.png); cursor:pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tree">
 <li class="cat">1
     <ul id="tree" class="visibleChild">
        <li class="cat">9
           <ul id="tree" class="visibleChild">
              <li class="cat">4</li>
              <li class="cat">5
                 <ul id="tree" class="hiddenChild">
                    <li class="cat">7</li>
                    <li class="cat">8</li>
                    <li class="cat">18</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
```

[Read this](http://sendesignz.com/how-to-create-expand-and-collapse-list-item-using-jquery/)